# Convert a time/character variable into numeric in SAS

Tags: sas, type-conversion

I am using the following code:

```
data time2;
set time;
varnew = put(varold, best12.) ; 
run;
```

The original variable measures duration, so the values are in seconds, and displayed like 0:03 etc. and I want to convert it into 0.03
There is a new column generated for varnew, however, no values are displayed. What could be the reason?

Comment: What data type and format is used for `varold`? You can find out for example by running `proc contents data=time; run;`

Expected output `varnew = 0.03` means 30 milliseconds?

Comment: Can you include example data (an example input of `time` dataset)?

Comment: @petr my var old is a char type. And I want to convert 0:04 to 4 seconds  or 0.04, which will be interpreted as 4 seconds

Comment: @Joe the column name is Time and the values there are described as char. The value output looks the following 0:04 0:12 0:01 0:11 etc. 0:04 is equal to 4 seconds and I want the output to be converted to a numeric value looking like 0.04 0.12 0.01 etc. I used the following command but it doesn’t work for me: data work.data02; set work.data01;
TIME2 = input(TIME, best12.)
;
run;

Comment: @joe Running a proc contents provides the following info for the time var: 71 TIME Char 8 $8.00 $8.00 TIME